# What are the names of all rank levels in Bejeweled 3 and Bejeweled Blitz?

Tags: bejeweled-3, bejeweled-blitz

There are 131 rank levels in Bejeweled as far as I know. What are the names of them?

Comment: Added the bejeweled blitz tag since they share ranks, and I could find this info anywhere else.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**EDIT:** Thanks to [Bejeweled wikia](http://bejeweled.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_ranks_in_Bejeweled_Blitz) pages, I learnt that there are now more levels in Bejeweled Blitz than I've known, in other words, 200 levels! I've appended the new levels to our list. Please see the extra info at the bottom as well!

---

It [seems](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=20671166&postcount=4) that the rank level names of Bejeweled 3 are identical to the ones of [Bejeweled Blitz](http://sites.google.com/site/bejeweledblitzguide/home/4-0-bejeweled-blitz/4-4-bejeweled-blitz-ranking-list):

1. Novice
2. Apprentice
3. Trainee
4. Beginner
5. Amateur
6. Jr. Appraiser
7. Appraiser
8. Gem Polisher
9. Gem Scraper
10. Gem Grinder
11. Jewel Thief
12. Jewel Scavenger
13. Gem Scrounger
14. Jr. Gemfinder
15. Gemfinder
16. Master Gemfinder
17. Jr. Jewelkeep
18. Jewelkeep
19. Master Jewelkeeper
20. Gemhunter Lv 1
21. Gemhunter Lv 2
22. Gemhunter Lv 3
23. Gemhunter Lv 4
24. Gemhunter Lv 5
25. Gemcrafter Lv 1
26. Gemcrafter Lv 2
27. Gemcrafter Lv 3
28. Gemcrafter Lv 4
29. Gemcrafter Lv 5
30. Jr. Gemstalker
31. Gemstalker
32. Sr. Gemstalker
33. Topaz Hunter
34. Onyx Hunter
35. Amethyst Hunter
36. Ruby Hunter
37. Emerald Hunter
38. Opal Hunter
39. Sapphire Hunter
40. Diamond Hunter
41. Topaz Blaster
42. Onyx Blaster
43. Amethyst Blaster
44. Ruby Blaster
45. Emerald Blaster
46. Opal Blaster
47. Sapphire Blaster
48. Diamond Blaster
49. Topaz Hoarder
50. Onyx Hoarder
51. Amethyst Hoarder
52. Ruby Hoarder
53. Emerald Hoarder
54. Opal Hoarder
55. Sapphire Hoarder
56. Diamond Hoarder
57. Topaz Master
58. Onyx Master
59. Amethyst Master
60. Ruby Master
61. Emerald Master
62. Opal Master
63. Sapphire Master
64. Diamond Master
65. Lapidary Lv 1
66. Lapidary Lv 2
67. Lapidary Lv 3
68. Lapidary Lv 4
69. Lapidary Lv 5
70. Master Lapidary
71. Supreme Lapidary
72. Ruby Wizard
73. Emerald Wizard
74. Opal Wizard
75. Sapphire Wizard
76. Diamond Wizard
77. Jeweled Wizard
78. Jeweled Mage
79. Jeweled Archmage
80. Jewelcrafter
81. Jewelforger
82. Bronze Blitzer
83. Silver Blitzer
84. Gold Blitzer
85. Platinum Blitzer
86. Bronze Master
87. Silver Master
88. Gold Master
89. Platinum Master
90. Jr.Bejeweler
91. Bejeweler
92. Sr. Bejeweler
93. Master Bejeweler
94. Mega Bejeweler
95. Hyper Bejeweler
96. Ultra Bejeweler
97. Prime Bejeweler
98. Ultimate Bejeweler
99. Bejeweled Regent
100. Bejeweled Demigod
101. Supreme Bejeweler
102. Jewelmagus Lv 1
103. Jewelmagus Lv 2
104. Jewelmagus Lv 3
105. Jewelmagus Lv 4
106. Jewelmagus Lv 5
107. Jewelmagus Lv 6
108. Jewelmagus Lv 7
109. Jewelmagus Lv 8
110. Jewelmagus Lv 9
111. Elder Jewelmagus
112. Jewelknight Lv 1
113. Jewelknight Lv 2
114. Jewelknight Lv 3
115. Jewelknight Lv 4
116. Jewelknight Lv 5
117. Jewelknight Lv 6
118. Jewelknight Lv 7
119. Jewelknight Lv 8
120. Jewelknight Lv 9
121. Elder Jewelknight
122. Bejewelian Lv 1
123. Bejewelian Lv 2
124. Bejewelian Lv 3
125. Bejewelian Lv 4
126. Bejewelian Lv 5
127. Bejewelian Lv 6
128. Bejewelian Lv 7
129. Bejewelian Lv 8
130. Bejewelian Lv 9
131. Elder Bejewelian
132. Topaz Regent
133. Onyx Regent
134. Amethyst Regent
135. Ruby Regent
136. Emerald Regent
137. Opal Regent
138. Sapphire Regent
139. Diamond Regent
140. Silver Regent
141. Gold Regent
142. Platinum Regent
143. Topaz Avatar
144. Onyx Avatar
145. Amethyst Avatar
146. Ruby Avatar
147. Emerald Avatar
148. Opal Avatar
149. Sapphire Avatar
150. Silver Avatar
151. Golden Avatar
152. Platinum Avatar
153. Topaz Paragon
154. Onyx Paragon
155. Amethyst Paragon
156. Ruby Paragon
157. Emerald Paragon
158. Opal Paragon
159. Sapphire Paragon
160. Diamond Paragon
161. Silver Paragon
162. Golden Paragon
163. Platinum Paragon
164. Topaz Ultimate
165. Onyx Ultimate
166. Amethyst Ultimate
167. Ruby Ultimate
168. Emerald Ultimate
169. Opal Ultimate
170. Sapphire Ultimate
171. Topaz Infinity
172. Onyx Infinity
173. Amethyst Infinity
174. Ruby Infinity
175. Emerald Infinity
176. Opal Infinity
177. Sapphire Infinity
178. Diamond Infinity
179. Silver Infinity
180. Golden Infinity
181. Platinum Infinity
182. (A Surprise!) (See Trivia)
183. (A Surprise!)
184. (A Surprise!)
185. (A Surprise!)
186. (A Surprise!)
187. (A Surprise!)
188. (A Surprise!)
189. (A Surprise!)
190. (A Surprise!)
191. (A Surprise!)
192. (A Surprise!)
193. (A Surprise!)
194. (A Surprise!)
195. (A Surprise!)
196. (A Surprise!)
197. (A Surprise!)
198. (A Surprise!)
199. (A Surprise!)
200. (A Surprise!)

> If you make it to level 200, by then you will have scored a cumulative
>   total of over 50 BILLION points!
>
> ### Trivia
>
> - Originally Bejeweled Blitz offered 131 unique names, then at some    point they increased this to 181 names.
> - All Level names 183 and beyond are the same as Level 182. But we don't want to spoil the last name for Bejeweled Blitz diehard players,
>     so we've marked them as a surprise!

Comment: Any diehard players around here? Could you tell us what the surprise name is?