# The meaning of Bejeweled ranks

Tags: bejeweled-3

A short time ago, a html5 version of Bejeweled was released as a google-chrome addon. By scoring in this game, you can gain ranks. Does anybody know if this ranks do anything?

By what I experienced, they don't seem to affect the gameplay or any features of the game. I kept playing for some time out of curiosity, but I did not find out anything about them.

Comment: Related: [What are the names of all 131 rank levels?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/16563/145)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is the [same](http://support.popcap.com/gplus-blitz-ranks) as in every other Bejeweled game, ranks are only a measure of how much you've played the game, and a way for you to compare your achievements against your friends.