# Ranks names in Diamond Mine

Tags: bejeweled-3

In the Bejeweled 3 - Diamond Mine game I have reached level 133 and the rank displayed from level 131 to 133 defaults to Elder Bejewelian.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

According to the top answer on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16563/what-are-the-names-of-all-rank-levels-in-bejeweled-3-and-bejeweled-blitz) the rank names for level 131-133 should be:

131: Elder Bejewelian

132: Topaz Regent

133: Onyx Regent